'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' and 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank' when testing Kepler
`I'm trying to replicate the Kepler project from Google Research (https://github.com/google/kepler) and encountered two errors that I can't seem to resolve. The first error is: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank' And the second error is: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'
These errors occur when running the active learning example from the Kepler repository. Here is a simplified version of the code where the errors occur:
# sngp_multihead_model.py
def _build_model(self) -> None:
    """Constructs model via Keras Functional API."""
    prev_layer = self._construct_preprocessing_layer()
    for i, (layer_size, dropout_rate) in enumerate(
        zip(self._model_config.layer_sizes, self._model_config.dropout_rates)):
      dense_layer = tf_keras.layers.Dense(
          layer_size,
          activation=self._model_config.activation)
      print(f"Type of dense_layer: {type(dense_layer)}")
      print(f"Dense layer config: {dense_layer.get_config()}")
        
      dense_layer = tfm.nlp.layers.SpectralNormalization(
          dense_layer,
          iteration=1,
          norm_multiplier=self._model_config.spectral_norm_multiplier,
          name=f"spectral_norm_{i}")
      print(f'current type of dense_layer after spectral normalization: {type(dense_layer)}')
      print(f"Dense layer config: {dense_layer.get_config()}")
      
      print(f"before passing to dense_layer's prev_layer: {type(prev_layer)} {type(prev_layer.shape)} {prev_layer}")
      if isinstance(prev_layer.shape, tuple):
            prev_layer.shape = tf.TensorShape(prev_layer.shape)
            print(f"after modification prev_layer: {type(prev_layer)} {type(prev_layer.shape)} {prev_layer}")
      prev_layer = dense_layer(prev_layer)
      print(f"after passing to dense_layer's prev_layer: {type(prev_layer)}")
      prev_layer = tf_keras.layers.Dropout(
          dropout_rate, name=f"dropout_{i}")(
              prev_layer)

    # Hardcoded hyperparameters are same as those in SNGP tutorial.
    classifier = tfm.nlp.layers.RandomFeatureGaussianProcess(
        self._num_plans,
        num_inducing=self._model_config.num_gp_random_features,
        normalize_input=False,
        scale_random_features=True,
        gp_cov_momentum=-1,
        name="output_gp_layer")
    logits, covariance_matrix = classifier(prev_layer)

    model = SNGPModel(
        classifier=classifier, inputs=self._inputs,
        outputs=[logits, covariance_matrix])
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
            learning_rate=self._model_config.learning_rate),
        loss=[self._model_config.loss, None],
        metrics=self._model_config.metrics)

    self._model = model

# spectral_normalization.py (from python3.10)
def call(self, inputs, *, training=None):
    print(f"Type of inputs: {type(inputs)}")
    print(f"Contents of inputs: {inputs}")
    # print(f"input shape: {inputs.shape.rank}") # tuple here
    
    training = self.do_power_iteration if training is None else training
    if training:
      u_update_op, v_update_op, w_update_op = self.update_weights(
          training=training)
      output = self.layer(inputs)
      w_restore_op = self.restore_weights()

      # Register update ops.
      self.add_update(u_update_op)
      self.add_update(v_update_op)
      self.add_update(w_update_op)
      self.add_update(w_restore_op)
    else:
      output = self.layer(inputs)
    
    print(f"Type of output: {type(output)}")
    print(f"Contents of output: {output}")

    return output

I have tried to debug it using multiple printing statments. The first error was solved using my current version of code, by transforming tuple into tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.TensorShape; However, after I fix the first one the second error occurred and I literally don't know why and which line of code since all of them points toward the line output = self.layer(inputs).
I've attached the referred code here, and there's no sign of string usage. Could you take a look at it and perhaps give me some suggestion? Thank you!
# base_wrapper.py (from python3.10)
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""Base class for wrapper layers.

Wrappers are layers that augment the functionality of another layer.
"""

import copy

from tf_keras.src.engine.base_layer import Layer
from tf_keras.src.saving import serialization_lib
from tf_keras.src.saving.legacy import serialization as legacy_serialization

# isort: off
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export

@keras_export("keras.layers.Wrapper")
class Wrapper(Layer):
    """Abstract wrapper base class.

    Wrappers take another layer and augment it in various ways.
    Do not use this class as a layer, it is only an abstract base class.
    Two usable wrappers are the `TimeDistributed` and `Bidirectional` wrappers.

    Args:
      layer: The layer to be wrapped.
    """

    def __init__(self, layer, **kwargs):
        try:
            assert isinstance(layer, Layer)
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Layer {layer} supplied to wrapper is"
                " not a supported layer type. Please"
                " ensure wrapped layer is a valid TF-Keras layer."
            )
        self.layer = layer
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape=None):
        print(f"reach here: {input_shape} {type(input_shape)}")
        if not self.layer.built:
            self.layer.build(input_shape)
            self.layer.built = True
        self.built = True

    @property
    def activity_regularizer(self):
        if hasattr(self.layer, "activity_regularizer"):
            return self.layer.activity_regularizer
        else:
            return None

    def get_config(self):
        try:
            config = {
                "layer": serialization_lib.serialize_keras_object(self.layer)
            }
        except TypeError:  # Case of incompatible custom wrappers
            config = {
                "layer": legacy_serialization.serialize_keras_object(self.layer)
            }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config, custom_objects=None):
        from tf_keras.src.layers import deserialize as deserialize_layer

        # Avoid mutating the input dict
        config = copy.deepcopy(config)
        use_legacy_format = "module" not in config
        layer = deserialize_layer(
            config.pop("layer"),
            custom_objects=custom_objects,
            use_legacy_format=use_legacy_format,
        )
        return cls(layer, **config)

